# In iOS, Is it possible to Get an Alert on arriving at specific location (or area). ? If yes, can any one provide an example for the same?

Tags: ios, geolocation, core-location, cllocationmanager

Hi current 'm trying to push an alert when user of the app arrive at particular. 'm new to iOS and dont have any idea about how this can be done. can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, have a look at the `CLLocationManager` documentation, specifically [startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges) and [startMonitoringForRegion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion%3a)